# How to use different logins for the same account?

Tags: support, login

I usually login using my Google account. But sometimes I don't want to login with my Google account, and I would like just to enter my username and password in Stack Exchange and logon to my current account. How to organize that?

I am trying to add more logins:

[image]

But I don't see "Create Stack Exchange login" or something like that.

Comment: ^ Appears it isn't that easy in case with SE login.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create an account with Stack Exchange OpenID.**
   You need an SE OpenID account to be able to add it to your recognized logins. Go to [this page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) and enter your details. Confirm the account using the link in the email you receive.
2. **Find your UUID and user link.**
   From the [SE OpenID homepage](https://openid.stackexchange.com), you should see a 'profile' view that looks like this:

   [image]

   (You will need to click on "Use your own URL to log in" to show the two code lines.)

   Copy the red-circled URL between the opening and closing quotes. This is your OpenID.
3. **Add your OpenID to your profile.**
   Go to [edit your logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) (that link will take you straight there). Clicking "add more logins..." takes you to the page from your screenshot. Paste the URL you copied in step 2 into the text box and click Add Credential.
4. **???**
5. Profit!